# Custom Eval function in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I`m using =Eval() function to convert formula written as text (mostly created by CONCATENATE funtion, for example i have cell =A2+B2 as text) to be an excel function. The =Eval() is custom function that can be found on many excel blogs and training sites. VBA code I use is:

```
Function Eval(Ref As String)
Application.Volatile
Eval = Evaluate(Ref)
enter code here
End Function
```

The problem i`m having is that this only works for formulas that doesn't contains other formulas in it. For example after i created cell with text (by using CONCATENATE): =2^(0.5) it works correctly, =Eval() gives me correct answer (1,414), but when i it for =sqrt(2) it gives me error.

Comment: You have something else going on here.    You are saying that you are using `=eval()` in your worksheet, but your function takes in a parameter.  If I put the value of `'sqrt(2)` into cell A4, and then use `=eval(A4)` in cell B4, I get the correct result.

Comment: What is the value of `ref` within your function when you get an error?

Comment: "You have something else going on here. You are saying that you are using =eval() in your worksheet, but your function takes in a parameter" 
I think i don`t fully understand what you mean. Notice that i`m not very familiar with VBA, i mostly use codes i find on the internet instead making them by myself. Error type i`m getting is #NAME?.

Comment: I am using my native language version of excel instead English. Did not think that is relevant but ia m running out of ideas.

Comment: What I'm saying is that to use the function you've posted, you need to put in `=Eval(A1)` or `=Eval(A2)` into some cell, not `=Eval()`.  If you put in `=Eval()` it won't do anything, you would get a `#VALUE#` error.  What happens if in the vba you put `Eval = Evaluate("sqrt(2)")` or `Eval = Evaluate(CStr("sqrt(2)"))`?

Comment: Also, what is the line `enter code here` for?  That would surely cause an error.

Comment: By default, `Evaluate(Ref)`will evaluate `Ref` *in the context of the active sheet*, which may not be the sheet containing your UDF.  `Application.Caller.Parent.Evaluate(Ref)` will force the evaluation to happen in the context of the sheet holding the UDF.

Comment: If you're getting a  #NAME error, the function can't be located.  You need to put it in a Module - not in a Worksheet or ThisWorkbook module.

Comment: Also since you are using vba to parse the formula, I believe it needs to be in US English format.  Which probably  why it works for us and not you.

Comment: Thank you very much for all answers. I believe the language is the issue. Unfortunately changing my system language only for one workbook seems very inconvenient. Is there any software for emulating system language? Or software that allow to change language of excel formulas?